# Replacing new-lines with more than a single character

Tags: shell, tr

Okay, so I know that the best way to replace new-lines is usually to do something like `tr '\n' ' '` or similar, however this only works for a single character.

What I'd like to do is replace new-lines, but insert something longer than a single character; in my case I actually want to add a timestamp so that something like this:

```
foo
bar
```

Becomes something like this:

```
[11:30] foo
[11:30] bar
```

I need to be able to do this by replacing the new-line character itself, as I can't guarantee that the last line of input will be complete at the time I process it (e.g - it could be output from `printf '%s' "foo"`, so has no line-ending yet). This means that using `read` line-by-line and just echoing with the timestamp added isn't an option.

Comment: But then the first line doesn't get a time stamp?

Comment: `sed 's/^/[11:30] /' file` will add a final newline if one is missing.

Comment: @tripleee I'll probably be adding the prefix to the first line separately using a variable to track whether it's is a new-line, or a continuation of the previous one (i.e - if the previous input didn't end with a new-line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bash-specific alternative so I figured I'd show it as an alternative answer for those with a `bash` shell (which is most people, except those currently suffering shell-shock ;)

```
#!/bin/bash
NL=$'\n'
data="foo${NL}bar"
printf '%s' "[11:30] ${data//$NL/$NL[11:30] }"
```

glenn jackman's proposal to use `perl` may be more portable for systems with other shells, but for bash this avoids the use of another program.

Answer (score 2):

Perl's good for this. Here's a file with no trailing newline:

```
$ od -c file
0000000   l   i   n   e   1  \n   l   i   n   e   2  \n   l   a   s   t
0000020       l   i   n   e   ,       n   o       n   e   w   l   i   n
0000040   e
0000041
$ perl -0777 -MTime::Piece -pe 's/^/ (localtime)->strftime("[%H:%M] ") /mge' file
[08:39] line1
[08:39] line2
[08:39] last line, no newline⏎
```

My shell ([fish](/questions/tagged/fish)) displays the "⏎" character to indicate no ending newline.